# Styling dropdown CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my dropdown list according to [image: this] image here. I am able to get the dropdown box but not sure how I can get it looking the same. 
Any input will be extermly helpful.

[image: This] is what I have so far.

I have tried looking up examples online but have not found something similar. 
Thanks for the help.

```css
div#setting-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1350px;
 display: inline-block;
}


div#setting-dropdown-content {
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    width: 237px;
    display: none;
    /* padding: 8px; */
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -105px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    padding: 15px;
}

div#setting-dropdown p {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 44px;
    font-family: 'Museo Slab 700';
}

img#setting-blue-arrow {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 121px;
    top: -44px;
}

div#setting-dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* display: none; */
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: 'Museo Slab 300';
    padding: 2px;
}

#setting-dropdown:hover #setting-dropdown-content {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Averios</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="averios.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="averios-header">
 <div id="setting-dropdown">
  <!-- SETTING DROPDOWN WILL GO HERE -->
  <p> SETTINGS </p>
  <img id="setting-blue-arrow" src="C:\Users\msehgal\Desktop\Averios\Images\downarrow.png" width="29" height="15"/>
  <div id="setting-dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Change Password</a>
   <a href="#">Change Security Settings</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="averios-logo">
  <img src="averioslogo.png" width="176" height="129">
 </div>
 <div id="setting-dropdown">
  <!-- SETTING DROPDOWN WILL GO HERE -->
 </div>
 <div id="header-hr">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="log-in">
 <div id="loginHeader">
  <h1>Portal</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="welcome-text">
  <p> Welcome name </p>
  <p> Your last login was time on date </p>
  <br>
  <p> Please select an application below to begin </p>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Raziasultana How is it even remotely related to the problem, but nice site tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-trigger {
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-trigger i {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.dropdown-trigger:hover i {
  background-color: #99f;
}
.dropdown-trigger:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  background-color: #99f;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
<div class="dropdown-trigger">
  Dropdown <i class="ion-chevron-down"></i>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed I am, just trying to figure out how I can integrate this with my code. If you could help me with that since I am not using list's

Comment: @Mani Definitely... Tell me more... The main thing I wanted to focus was the positioning.

Comment: How can I move this to chat to tell you more? There is alot of code and I dont want to paste it all here. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Mani Keep talking something, until it pushes to chat.

Comment: alright, so the code you see so far. I am using image because that is the only way I knew I can do this but seeing there is a way to do this without using multiple images is very helpful, i am still new to CSS to learning.

Comment: @Mani Chat enabled. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127825/discussion-between-mani-and-praveen-kumar).